# How do I run a shell command from inside a Behat test?

Tags: laravel, behat, laravel-artisan

I'm working on laravel 5 app and I need to create an artisan command. I'm using Behat as my testing framework. I know I can test the state of my database inside of behat. I want to run a command like"

php artisan my:command

from inside a behat step. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Inside your `FeatureContext` class:

```
/**
 * @When I run :command
 */
public function iRun($command)
{
    $this->output = shell_exec($command);
}
```

If you are using Symfony console component, take a look at https://gist.github.com/tPl0ch/6706427

You can even describe your commands like on https://gist.github.com/everzet/1683634.

Comment: You can also find this in the documentation of behat. http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/quick_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to do this. Since I'm running an artisan command, I can use the Artisan facade.

```
/**
     * @Given I run the artisan command :command with args :args
     * @param $command
     * @param $args
     */
    public function iRunTheArtisanCommandWithArgs($command, $args)
    {
        \Artisan::call($command, [$args]);
    }
```